# Best practice to handle errors in Mongoose's post hooks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

For example, I define a post hook for the `update` event of a model schema. If a document is updated because of a request, then the post hook will trigger some async tasks. However, if any async task fails, I want to log this error with the request context so that I could know this error is caused by which request at least.

However, the `post` hook doesn't receive flow control, and I can't find an obvious way to pass the `req` object into the `post` hook too.

Reference: [Mongoose.js Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Mongoose 4.0+ starts to support async post hooks (found in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/1977), but the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) hasn't been updated accordingly yet...

With the async post hooks I should be able to handle errors using `next(err)` and then use a middleware to handle it (log it down for example).